# how to add security to updating rows in a database PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, security

Say in my ajax request page, I have a row of results pulled from the database that looks something like this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<p value='".$taskId."' class='titleRsltTask'>".$taskTitle."</p><br>";
}
```

Here `$taskId` is the primary key for the row returned. When the results are returned to the DOM, a user *can inspect and change this id*. Say I have another ajax request to delete or update the above results when `.titleRsltTask` is clicked,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.titleRsltTask').click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#taskResults').load('Includes/updateTask.inc.php', {
      Id: id
  });
});
```

which uses the value `$taskId` to find which row to update in `updateTask.inc.php`.

1. What are some ways I can verify that the row that the user is updating belongs to them so that they can't update any rows in the table by changing the value in the inspect element?
2. Is there a better way to set this up in the first place? Does using an SSL help in any way?
3. Are there other security measures you want to point out, I'd be glad to hear them.

I've done some research on authorization, authentication, and encryption but still not exactly sure what to do in this situation.

Comment: If users downvote a question they are suggested to write a reason why, so that the question can be improved - I hope other users note this comment.  @MichaelW44 you may be able to improve your question however to make it clearer.

Comment: The question is vague enough to actually give a good security recommendation. All I can say is that you'll need to implement authentication in order to verify that the correct user is updating his own rows. SSL will prevent a thirdparty from intercepting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I do understand your concern about security, as the value returned are auto incremented numbers.

Using a ssl wont encrypt or provide you any security with such things.

1. SSL only encrypts other users connection to your website.
2. SSL encrypts the packets transmitted to your website.

One way you could apply additional layer of security is by encrypting the numeric id returned from the server using some salt algorithm and displaying it in the view in encrypted format.And then decrypt it at the server.

Updating and changing the encrypted value wont do any good even if someone changes it using inspect element, as that would not be processed into a valid value when being decrypted in the server.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Makes sense, I'll be looking into encryptions some more. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your table structure.  If users are only able to change certain row, then on each row include the user ID that can edit it, use authentication with the request (by including a session cookie etc), and add that logic to the `UPDATE` command.  If a group of users can change certain rows, then have an extra column specifying the group ID/privilege, and ensure each user has a privilege level set.

Comment: My table structure is actually already set up with the user ID in each row from when the user originally inserted the task. If I got it right, you're saying to query out the user ID from that row being updated, check if it matches the user ID in the session variable, and if it does then execute the update command for that row? Hope I worded that right

Comment: More or less, yes - if you only want that user to be able to edit the row, then you need to send information to the server somehow or other that it is that user.  Sending the user ID would be insecure, as anyone could edit it, so you should verify the user IS that user by use of a session.